# that or which in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I'm always confused about using "that" and "which" in a sentence. I have learned that "which" is used in non-defining clauses (this clause can be omitted), while "that" is used in defining clauses and cannot omitted. However, I cannot decide which one to select in my sentence:

> This structure consists of 2 layers: a physical layer **...that/which...**
>   contains sensors and a logical layer **...that/which...** contains logic.

Comment: 'Which' sounds considerably better to me as a native speaker in both cases. I think it is because the clause is just adding information to describe the physical layer, and so you could leave it out or put it in brackets.

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether the relative clauses in your example are intended to be defining or non-defining. Please clarify.

Comment: @BillJ I'm not sure. In the first part I'm talking about the components of a physical layer, so it seems to be defining, am I right?

Comment: Is there more than one kind of 'physical layer' / 'logical layer' so that defining relatives are necessary?

Comment: @BillJ No there is only one "physical layer" and one "logical layer"

Comment: OK, so they are non-defining relatives, in which case only "which" is possible. You can't use "that" in non-defining relatives.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that a clearer way to structure this sentence would actually eliminate the relatives altogether:  **This structure consists of two layers: a physical layer containing sensors and a logical layer containing logic.**